# How to instatiate a Django Form dynamically by string?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to write an app for Django. I want my users to be able to collect certain types of data, for instance samples, videos, etc... The app is called collector and for each type of item there is a class and a form that goes along with it.

Example Class:

```
class CreateTextView(CreateItemView):    
    form_class = TextForm
    model = Text

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateTextView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['item_type'] = 'text' 
        return context
```

Example Form:

```
class TextForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Text

        fields = COMMON_FIELDS + ('text',)
```

As you can see, the actual view is inheriting from CreateItemView. I want as much of the functionality to be defined for CreateItemView so that I don't have to do it individually for all item classes. That has been working for the most part, but it gets a bit tricky when I try to process forms with data.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = TextForm(request.POST) # line 2
    form = getattr(TextForm, '__init__')(data=request.POST) # line 3

    if form.is_valid():           
        # Add owner information.
        item = form.save(commit=False)
        item.owner = request.user
        item.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('collector:index'))

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

In Line 2 you can see how I would handle the form if there was only one type of form. Line 3 is what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to use the `context['item_type']` to dynamically choose the right form and instantiate it with the given data.

Now the problem lies with the `__init__`-method which I have never defined anywhere. When I pass only POST.request to `__init__`, it complains about not having a self. When I pass the additional self, it complains about how CreateTextView has no _meta-attribute and so on. I just can't find the right combination of argumentes to satisfy the `__init__`-method. I can't look up it's definition either, because I didn't define it. I then followed the definition of the parent classes in the django framework which led me to a couple of complex functions that looked like factories. That didn't really help me...

Now I know how to use the `TextForm()`-initiation. Is there a way to fetch this method dynamically with `getattr()`? That would save me the hassle with `__init__`. If not, how do I provide `__init__` with the correct self-instance?

---

As mentioned below, I have changed my classes a little bit. I no longer use context to store the item_type, instead I use a class variable to have easy acces to the item_type within a view. My post method is defined in the mother class CreateItemView and looks like this now:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        form_cls = ITEM_TYPE_MAP[self.item_type]
    except KeyError:
        # invalid item_type. raise a meaningful error here
        raise Exception('Invalid item type.')
    form = form_cls(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():           
        # Add owner information.
        item = form.save(commit=False)
        item.owner = request.user
        item.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('collector:index'))

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean and quite simple solution to look for is using a dictionary to map the `item_type` values to actual form classes:

```
ITEM_TYPE_MAP = {
    "foo": TextForm,
    "bar": SomeOtherForm,
}
```

You’d put that dictionary at some global place and use it from within the controller like this:

```
item_type = context['item_type']
try:
    form_cls = ITEM_TYPE_MAP[item_type]
except KeyError:
    # invalid item_type. raise a meaningful error here
    raise
form = form_cls(request.POST)
```

You cannot directly call `__init__` usually, because there’s more than that to instanciate an object. Python will also call `__new__` on the *class* of the object, so the only way to be sure is to go through the actual constructor, which is calling the type.

This is what happens above, by first fetching the type into `form_cls` and then calling the type (i.e. the constructor).

Comment: Thanky you for this beautiful answer. It was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about that syntax-variant where you just add () to a variable. I initially learned with more conservative languages, mostly Java.
I no longer use the context though. I have just created a member variable in my classes called item_type so that I have easy access to the type from within the class.